# Would it be possible to add Amplify to an existing react project?

Tags: aws-amplify

Currently have a react project, want to add Amplify's backend and authentication - would this be possible? Tutorials explain how to create a new react app / backend src.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just start with initializing the backend. You can read the instructions [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/setup/q/integration/react/#initialize-a-new-backend).